# BLCR install in Centos

Tags: c++, installation, centos, checkpoint, blcr

I'm working for make checkpoint for my program, and I find that BLCR might can help me.
I want to install it on my server. I download it with version 0.8.5,
However, it raises `Configure error: Unable to use Kernal 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64.`

How can I solve it or is there any other lib can replace it?

```
Configure error: Unable to use Kernel 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 -unable to determine how to call attach_pid()
```

Comment: Any attempt to follow the manual https://hpcworks.wordpress.com/2017/05/26/build-install-notes-for-blcr-slurm-on-centos-7-3/? In short, you older BLCR versions https://crd.lbl.gov/divisions/amcr/computer-science-amcr/class/research/past-projects/BLCR/berkeley-lab-checkpoint-restart-for-linux-blcr-downloads/

Comment: Hi @273K, it seems there are some bug will make the lib. Is there any other replace tools that I can used?

Comment: Looks like it's a 10 year old tool developed by academics. There is a good chance it works only with some specific linux kernel versions. Or maybe you are missing some linux kernel devel libraries. Better ask the authors of that tool. You can also check for additional configure options `./configure --help`, maybe something to override the required kernel.